# LinkedList last value not getting parsed

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm doing a leetcode question: Adding two numbers

One of the testCases is not passing and I'm at the end of my wits as to why the last value is getting missed my my program. Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        //have to use bit addition here
        if(l1==null){
            return l2;
        }
        if(l2==null){
            return l1;
        }

        int b1=0, b2=0, resBit = 0, carryBit=0;
        ListNode res = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode dummy = res;

        while(l1!=null && l2!=null){
            resBit = l1.val+l2.val+carryBit;
            if(resBit >9){
                carryBit=1;
                resBit=resBit%10;
            }
            else{
                carryBit=0;
            }
            dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
            l1=l1.next;
            l2=l2.next;
            dummy=dummy.next;
        }

        //add any remaining numbers to our result

        if(l1!=null){
            System.out.println(l1.val);
            if(carryBit!=0){
                resBit = l1.val+carryBit;
                if(resBit >9){
                    carryBit=1;
                    resBit=resBit%10;
                }
                else{
                    carryBit=0;
                }
                dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
            }
            else{

                dummy.next = new ListNode(l1.val);
            }
            l1=l1.next;
            System.out.println(l1.val);
            dummy=dummy.next;
        }

        if(l2!=null){
            if(carryBit!=0){
                resBit = l2.val+carryBit;
                if(resBit >9){
                    carryBit=1;
                    resBit=resBit%10;
                }
                else{
                    carryBit=0;
                }
                dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
            }
            else{
                dummy.next = new ListNode(l2.val);
            }
            l2=l2.next;
            dummy=dummy.next;
        }

        if(carryBit!=0){
            dummy.next = new ListNode(carryBit);
        }


        //remove the -1 used to create the LL initially
        res = res.next;

        return res;
    }
}
```

Here're the details for the failing test-case:

Wrong Answer
Runtime: 0 ms
Your input
[9,1,6]
[0]

stdout
1
6

Output
[9,1]
Expected
[9,1,6]

As you can see the 6 is getting missed by my code. The 6 is however getting printed in the remaining l1 elements parsing loop. Why is it getting missed?

The only way it could be missed if the loop is not getting run, which means the program is getting 6 as null, hence skipping a value. Not sure why that's happening. Is this the right chain of thought?

Any new information, or improvements are greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `while(l1!=NULL)` instead of `if(l1!=NULL)`. same for l2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a little bit of shameless promo, check out [my solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/543759/JavaC%2B%2B-Basic-Elementary-Math). But I can point the reason why it isn't working, and some other things that are good practices
First of all, what is `b1` and `b2` for? Am I missing something, because I didn't see it a single time in your code.

Over here:

```
if(resBit >9){
    carryBit=1;
    resBit=resBit%10;
}
```

You're setting the carry bit to `1`. However, you have to set it to `sum / 10` in case the sum arises to something like `20`. In the actual problem, there isn't any test case that will give you a problem with this, however with larger numbers this will cause errrors.

The bigger reason is this part:

```
if(l1!=null){
```

and

```
if(l2!=null){
```

You are only checking if it not null once. However, if the difference in size of the two lists are 2 or more, then `l1` or `l2` will still be non-null when you terminate. So, you have to change the `if` to a `while` loop.

When I applied these changes, it worked. Here is the result:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        //have to use bit addition here
        if(l1==null){
            return l2;
        }
        if(l2==null){
            return l1;
        }

        int resBit = 0, carryBit=0;
        ListNode res = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode dummy = res;

        while(l1!=null && l2!=null){
            resBit = l1.val+l2.val+carryBit;
            if(resBit >9){
                carryBit=resBit / 10;
                resBit=resBit%10;
            }
            else{
                carryBit=0;
            }
            dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
            l1=l1.next;
            l2=l2.next;
            dummy=dummy.next;
        }

        //add any remaining numbers to our result

        while(l1!=null){
            if(carryBit!=0){
                resBit = l1.val+carryBit;
                if(resBit >9){
                    carryBit=1;
                    resBit=resBit%10;
                }
                else{
                    carryBit=0;
                }
                dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
            }
            else{

                dummy.next = new ListNode(l1.val);
            }
            l1=l1.next;
            dummy=dummy.next;
        }

        while(l2!=null){
            if(carryBit!=0){
                resBit = l2.val+carryBit;
                if(resBit >9){
                    carryBit=1;
                    resBit=resBit%10;
                }
                else{
                    carryBit=0;
                }
                dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
            }
            else{
                dummy.next = new ListNode(l2.val);
            }
            l2=l2.next;
            dummy=dummy.next;
        }

        if(carryBit!=0){
            dummy.next = new ListNode(carryBit);
        }


        //remove the -1 used to create the LL initially
        res = res.next;

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a solution in progress, b1 and b2 were supposed to be the vals from linked lists l1 and l2, but I directly used them instead and forgot to remove them from the code. If you see the solution I posted, I realized and then used them. Thanks for the answer! I see the silly mistake, I'll take a break now :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to skip my buggy approach, and the solution works. However, it still leaves the original question unsolved.

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        //have to use bit addition here
        if(l1==null){
            return l2;
        }
        if(l2==null){
            return l1;
        }

        int b1=0, b2=0, resBit = 0, carryBit=0;
        ListNode res = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode dummy = res;

        while(l1!=null || l2!=null){
            b1 = (l1 != null) ? l1.val : 0;
            b2 = (l2 != null) ? l2.val : 0;
            resBit = b1+b2+carryBit;
            if(resBit >9){
                carryBit=1;
                resBit=resBit%10;
            }
            else{
                carryBit=0;
            }
            dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
            if(l1!=null){
                l1=l1.next;
            }

            if(l2!=null){
                l2=l2.next;
            }

            dummy=dummy.next;
        }

        //add carry to our result if carry is not 0
        if(carryBit!=0){
            dummy.next = new ListNode(carryBit);
        }


        //remove the -1 used to create the LL initially
        res = res.next;
        return res;
    }
```

As I said, this solution succeeds the test case. However, I'm still not sure why the previous code wasn't working. Please respond if you see out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

//add any remaining numbers to our result

```
    if(l1!=null){
        System.out.println(l1.val);
        if(carryBit!=0){
            resBit = l1.val+carryBit;
            if(resBit >9){
                carryBit=1;
                resBit=resBit%10;
            }
            else{
                carryBit=0;
            }
            dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
        }
        else{

            dummy.next = new ListNode(l1.val);
        }
        l1=l1.next;
        System.out.println(l1.val);
        dummy=dummy.next;
    }

    if(l2!=null){
        if(carryBit!=0){
            resBit = l2.val+carryBit;
            if(resBit >9){
                carryBit=1;
                resBit=resBit%10;
            }
            else{
                carryBit=0;
            }
            dummy.next = new ListNode(resBit);
        }
        else{
            dummy.next = new ListNode(l2.val);
        }
        l2=l2.next;
        dummy=dummy.next;
    }

    if(carryBit!=0){
        dummy.next = new ListNode(carryBit);
    }
```

Use while loop not if, in short.

As you can see the above code runs only once if any of the `LinkedList` becomes null. And since your test case was:

```
L1: [9,1,6]
L2: [0]
```

As you can notice, after 1st addition:

- L1 pointer becomes = {1}
- L2 pointer becomes {null}.

Then you are doing only addition of the L1 pointer once, not till L1 becomes {null}.

You resolved it by using the while loop in the solution you gave in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. The question has been answered though.